# Writing identifier tool task with ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am getting all layers information on map using identifier.But i want if all layers is enable on map if i clicked on one layer i need only that information not all layers information using identifier in arcgis javascript api 3.17.here is the my code

```
function mapReady() {
              map.on("click", executeIdentifyTask);
              //create identify tasks and setup parameters
              identifyTask = new IdentifyTask("URL");

              identifyParams = new IdentifyParameters();
              identifyParams.tolerance = 3;
              identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
              //identifyParams.layerIds = [35, 0, 5, 13, 8, 12, 14, 3, 15, 2, 7, 17, 18, 19, 1, 6, 9, 20, 21];
              //identifyParams.layerIds = [20, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13];

              //ask
              identifyParams.layerIds = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 70, 71, 72];
              identifyParams.layerOption = IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_VISIBLE;
              identifyParams.width = map.width;
              identifyParams.height = map.height;
          }

          function executeIdentifyTask(event) {
              identifyParams.geometry = event.mapPoint;
              identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;

              var deferred = identifyTask
                .execute(identifyParams)
                .addCallback(function (response) {
                    // response is an array of identify result objects
                    // Let's return an array of features.
                    return arrayUtils.map(response, function (result) {
                        var feature = result.feature;
                        var layerName = result.layerName;

                        feature.attributes.layerName = layerName;
                        if (layerName == 'District') {
                            //ask
                            //console.log(feature.attributes.AssemblyCode);
                            var taxParcelTemplate = new InfoTemplate("District Details", "DistrictCode:${DistrictCode}<br /> DistrictName:${DistrictName}");
                            feature.setInfoTemplate(taxParcelTemplate);
                        }
                        else if (layerName == 'Taluk') {
                            var taxParcelTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Taluk Details", "TalukCode:${TalukCode}<br /> TalukName:${TalukName}");
                            feature.setInfoTemplate(taxParcelTemplate);
                            // outFields: ["*"]
                        }
                        else if (layerName == 'Parliment') {
                            var taxParcelTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Parlimentary Details", "ParliamentCode:${ParliamentCode}<br /> ParliamentName:${ParliamentName}");
                            feature.setInfoTemplate(taxParcelTemplate);
                            // outFields: ["*"]
                        }
                        else if (layerName == 'Assembly') {
                            var taxParcelTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Assembly Details", "AssemblyCode:${AssemblyCode}<br /> AssemblyName:${AssemblyName}");
                            feature.setInfoTemplate(taxParcelTemplate);
                            // outFields: ["*"]
                        }
                        else if (layerName == 'Hobli') {
                            var taxParcelTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Hobli Details", "HobliCode:${HobliCode}<br /> HobliName:${HobliName}");
                            feature.setInfoTemplate(taxParcelTemplate);
                            // outFields: ["*"]
                        }
                            //info details yet to add
                        else if (layerName == 'Grampanchayat') {
                            var taxParcelTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Grampanchayat Details", "GrampanchayatCode:${GrampanchayatCode}<br /> GrampanchayatName:${GrampanchayatName}");
                            feature.setInfoTemplate(taxParcelTemplate);
                            // outFields: ["*"]
                        }
                        else if (layerName == 'Village') {
                            var taxParcelTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Village Details", "Code:${Code}<br /> Name:${Name}");
                            feature.setInfoTemplate(taxParcelTemplate);
                            // outFields: ["*"]
                        }
              return feature;
                    });
                });


              map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
              map.infoWindow.show(event.mapPoint);
          }
```

Comment: can you explain more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

firstly you change layerIds for only searching layer, if you search all layer delete this code;

```
identifyParams.layerIds = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 70, 71, 72];
```

secondly change LAYER_OPTION_VISIBLE to LAYER_OPTION_TOP, so it only searching top layer in your layer list

```
identifyParams.layerOption = IdentifyParameters. LAYER_OPTION_TOP;
```